# SQL DATETIMEOFFSET (Eventdatetime ) - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetimeoffset

When I try to convert the value '2021-03-01**T00**:08:41.000Z' into a DATETIMEOFFSET it is successful. But when I try to convert the value '2021-03-01**T0**:08:41.000Z' into a DATETIMEOFFSET its failing.

After analysis, with the following script one is not valid data. But I need to process with both the format.

Please can someone suggest how I can store'2021-03-01T**0**:08:41.000Z' also as a DATETIMEOFFSET value?

```
select ISDATE('2021-03-01T00:08:41.000Z')  --> 1 
select ISDATE('2021-03-01T0:08:41.000Z')   --> 0
```

SQL Script- error with T**0** , no error with T**00**:

```
declare @jsonArray varchar(max) ='[{   "number": "AC100",  "eventdatetime": "2021-04-09T0:00:00+00:00",  "val": "0"}]';

WITH jsonData AS (
    SELECT  number, eventdatetime,val
    FROM OPENJSON(@jsonArray)
    WITH (
        number VARCHAR(50),
        eventdatetime DATETIMEOFFSET ,
        val VARCHAR(50)
    )
)
SELECT number, eventdatetime, val FROM jsonData WHERE val IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Your second format isn't supported - where are your strings coming from? Correct them before they get to you.

Comment: Thanks Dale for quick response, but unfortunately data is flowing from other source.  I am looking is there anyway that I can handling incoming @jsonArray value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some string manipulation to detect this case and correct for it. Find the 'T', find the next ':' and if there is only one character between them, insert a '0'.

The following is based on the assumption that this is the *only* data anomaly you are dealing with. It may need to be made more robust if the data can be incorrect in other ways.

```
select x.TestDate
  , cast(case when SecondPos-FirstPos = 2 then substring(x.TestDate,1,FirstPos) + '0' + substring(x.TestDate,FirstPos+1,len(x.TestDate)) else x.TestDate end as datetimeoffset(0)) Corrected
from (
  values
  ('2021-03-01T00:08:41.000Z')
  ,('2021-03-01T0:08:41.000Z')) x (TestDate)
cross apply (
  values
  (charindex('T',TestDate), charindex(':',TestDate))
) y (FirstPos, SecondPos);
```

Ideally of course you would ask your downstream source to correct their formatting and provide a valid `datetimeoffset` format.